# Javascript adding to variable

Tags: javascript, for-loop

When I click the below code it shows `locationsgohere` as blank and when I click it again the `locationsgohere` shows the data like it should.

Say for instance I had `London, UK` in the `textarea` `#id` this should show the `output` as `var locations = [['London,51.511214,-0.119824]],` but only if I click twice. the first time I click it shows just `var locations = [],`

If I click it three times it just shows the following `var locations = [['London,51.511214,-0.119824]['London,51.511214,-0.119824]],`

Have I done something wrong in this `for` loop?

```
var locationsgohere,output;
$('.generate').click(function(){
    var temp_addresses = document.getElementById("gps").value.split("\n");
    for(var i=0;i<temp_addresses.length;i++){
        addresses.push(temp_addresses[i]);
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': temp_addresses[i]}, function(response, status) {
            geocode_results[i] = new Array();
            geocode_results[i]['status'] = status;
            var top_location = response[0];
            var lat = Math.round(top_location.geometry.location.lat() * 1000000)/1000000;
            var lng = Math.round(top_location.geometry.location.lng() * 1000000)/1000000;
            geocode_results[i]['lat'] = lat;
            geocode_results[i]['lng'] = lng;
            geocode_results[i]['l_type'] = top_location.geometry.location_type;
            locationsgohere += "['"+top_location.address_components[0].long_name+","+lat+","+lng+"]";
        });
    }
    if (!locationsgohere){
        locationsgohere = '';
    }
    output = 'var locations = ['+locationsgohere+'],';// JavaScript Document
});
```

Updated code

```
var temp_addresses = document.getElementById("gps").value.split("\n");
    var todo = temp_addresses.length; // count the remaining requests
    //  for(var i=0;i<temp_addresses.length;i++){
    for(var i=0;i<temp_addresses.length;i++){
        (function(i){ // protect i in an immediately called function
            addresses.push(temp_addresses[i]);
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': temp_addresses[i]}, function(response, status) {
                geocode_results[i] = new Array();
                geocode_results[i]['status'] = status;
                var top_location = response[0];
                var lat = Math.round(top_location.geometry.location.lat() * 1000000)/1000000;
                var lng = Math.round(top_location.geometry.location.lng() * 1000000)/1000000;
                geocode_results[i]['lat'] = lat;
                geocode_results[i]['lng'] = lng;
                geocode_results[i]['l_type'] = top_location.geometry.location_type;
//              locationsgohere += "['"+top_location.address_components[0].long_name+","+lat+","+lng+"]";
            });
            if (--todo===0) { // finished
                output = 'var locations = ['+(locationsgohere||'')+'],';
            }
            console.log(locationsgohere);
        })(i);
//  var output = 'var locations = ['+locationsgohere+'],';
    }
```

Comment: `geocode()`  is asynchronous, so your output is at the wrong place ...

Comment: I am not familiar with `geocode()`, but I assume it is asynchronous.  Therefore your output needs to go into the callback function.

Answer (score 2):

The problems you have are

- that when the callback you pass to the **asynchronous** `geocode` function is called, the `for` loop has ended and `i` has the value of end of loop.
- that you build the output too soon, you must wait for all requests to be finished

Here's a solution :

```
var temp_addresses = document.getElementById("gps").value.split("\n");
var todo = temp_addresses.length; // count the remaining requests
for(var i=0;i<temp_addresses.length;i++){
    (function(i){ // protect i in an immediately called function
        addresses.push(temp_addresses[i]);
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': temp_addresses[i]}, function(response, status) {
            geocode_results[i] = new Array();
            geocode_results[i]['status'] = status;
            var top_location = response[0];
            var lat = Math.round(top_location.geometry.location.lat() * 1000000)/1000000;
            var lng = Math.round(top_location.geometry.location.lng() * 1000000)/1000000;
            geocode_results[i]['lat'] = lat;
            geocode_results[i]['lng'] = lng;
            geocode_results[i]['l_type'] = top_location.geometry.location_type;
            locationsgohere += "['"+top_location.address_components[0].long_name+","+lat+","+lng+"]";
            if (--todo===0) { // finished
                output = 'var locations = ['+(locationsgohere||'')+'],';

                // Use output HERE !

            }
        });
        console.log(locationsgohere);
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and `locationsgohere` returns as blank in the `output` even though I will update the original post with the new script I am using

Comment: @Beardy I wasn't clear I think. I detailled the code to use. Be careful to use output precisely where I say (or in a function called from that point).

Answer (score 0):

This is because we don't know when the code inside the asynchronous geocode callback is going to run.

```
geocoder.geocode(... function() {
  // This code will run at some point... 
  // either before, or after the "code below"
});

// code below
```

You need to detect when the last callback in the loop has fired, and then display the locations.